# Pandas Nested DataFrame assignment

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
    prefix  operator_name   country_name    mno_subscribers 
0   267.0   Airtel          Botswana        490
1   373.0   Orange          Moldova         207
2   248.0   Airtel          Seychelles      490
3   91.0    Reliance        Bostwana        92
4   233.0   Vodafone        Bostwana        516
```

I am trying to acheive this:

```
    prefix  operator_name   country_name    mno_subscribers  operator_proba 
0   267.0   Airtel          Botswana        490              0.045
1   373.0   Orange          Moldova         207              0.004
2   248.0   Airtel          Seychelles      490              0.135
3   91.0    Reliance        India           92               0.945
4   233.0   Vodafone        Ghana           516              0.002
```

With this:

```
countries = df["country_name"].unique()
df["operator_proba"] = 0

for country in countries:
    country_name = df[df["country_name"] == country]

    for operator in country:
        mno_sum = country_name["mno_subscribers"].sum()
        df["operator_proba"]["country_name"] = country_name["mno_subscribers"] / mno_sum
```

Where am I going wrong in assigning the `operator_proba` to the original DataFrame?

Comment: What does the second `for` loop `for operator in country` do? Also can you make the example reproducible? It's not clear how you can derive `operator_proba` from the data you give.

Comment: There are duplicate operators per country. The probability should be unique to the set of operators per country. Summing to one.

Comment: Just guess here. Does `df['operator_proba'] = df.groupby(['country_name', 'operator_name']).mno_subscribers.transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())` work for you?

Comment: Yes, it runs, but each record is 1.0. They should all be floats unless there is only one operator in the country.

Comment: I can not reason with the data you give. Take a look at [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: Are Botswana and Bostwana supposed to be the same countries? Is that a typo on your side, or a typo on the input data side?

Comment: @Psidom, apologies. Edited for completeness and understanding.

Comment: country_name has duplicates, so does operator_name, but not for the combination of the two (such as an index).

Comment: You *completely* changed your question with your last edit. I've reverted that. If you have anything new while the original question still holds, *add* it to your question, don't overwrite the old question. Otherwise, ask a new question.

Comment: @Evert, understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
    df["operator_proba"]["country_name"] = country_name["mno_subscribers"] / mno_sum
```

can't really work, since `df["operator_proba"]` is a column (or Series); you can't use `["country_name"]` indexing on that.
That is probably why things don't work for you.

It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve, but I guess this may work:

```
df['operator_proba'] = df.groupby('country_name')['mno_subscribers'].apply(lambda x : x/x.sum())
```

This saves you a double loop, and is more Pandas-style (there are probably even nicer ways to compute this). The result is:

```
   prefix operator_name country_name  mno_subscribers  operator_proba
0   267.0        Airtel     Botswana              490        1.000000
1   373.0        Orange      Moldova              207        1.000000
2   248.0        Airtel   Seychelles              490        1.000000
3    91.0      Reliance     Bostwana               92        0.151316
4   233.0      Vodafone     Bostwana              516        0.848684
```

with the limited data set (and Botswana/Bostwana difference), most "probabilities" are 1.